# How to prove $\csc^{2}(x)-\cot^{2}(x)+\tan^{2}(x)=\sec^{2}(x)$?

Tags: trigonometry

How to prove $\csc^{2}(x)-\cot^{2}(x)+\tan^{2}(x)=\sec^{2}(x)$?

I started with **$\frac{1}{\sin^{2}(x)} - \frac{\cos^{2}(x)}{\sin^{2}(x)} + \frac{\sin^{2}(x)}{\cos^{2}(x)} = \sec^{2}(x)$** but I am stuck now.

Comment: Please use MathJax when formatting your question: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: Writing everything in terms of $\sin$ and $\cos$ except the right-hand side of a purported identity seems like a good idea.

Comment: What you have so far is fine.  Find a common denominator, and add the fractions.  Simplify the numerator.  Use the identity $\sin^2 x + \cos^2 x = 1$ to hopefully cancel one of the factors in the denominator.

Answer (score 1):

$csc^2(x) - cot^2(x) + tan^2(x) = sec^2(x)$

$csc^2(x) - [csc^2(x) -1]  + [sec^2(x) -1] = sec^2(x)$

$sec^2(x) = sec^2(x)$

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).